# Working with jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

So im trying to do some animations on a personal project im working on but i've new to jquery and im having trouble understanding how it works. I've been learning through using a plug in called jquery.transit(http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) and i have tried getting it to work but there is something im missing. The documentation doesn't seem that great either because I don't see any good examples of the transitions working, just snippets of the jquery that don't seem complete.

For now, I have this code which I was try to get to animate my header links, and the animation works itself, but it only works once, and stops working after the initial hover. How can I get this working? Code:

```
 $('.navlinks').hover(function(){
        $(this).transition({
        perspective: '500px',
        rotateX: 360,
        rotateY: 360
        })
    });
```

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle showing what you're trying to do?

Comment: I think they may expect you to use handle mouseenter and mouseleave events, so that you do the animation, then reverse it in the right context. Hover only gets called once therefore it rotates 360 and that's it.

Comment: yeah that seems to be the problem, let me update some code

Comment: There seems to be a test suite here, https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit/tree/master/test

Comment: not sure what to do with that

Comment: Well they are using mouseenter and mouseleave to reverse their (absolute) properties, so that's enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsfiddle using the exact code that you provided and it works just fine. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/a4m6aaL8/

```
<ul>
    <li class="navlinks">Link 1</li>
    <li class="navlinks">Link 2</li>
    <li class="navlinks">Link 3</li>
</ul>

$('.navlinks').hover(function(){
    $(this).transition({
        perspective: '500px',
        rotateX: 360,
        rotateY: 360
    });
});
```

Edit: maybe you're imported the library or jquery incorrectly, or in the wrong order?

Edit: it must have to do with the library you're using, when replacing the transition stuff with something like fadein/out, it works everytime when hovered. http://jsfiddle.net/obmk4a9L/

Edit: here's the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/0qogt8m7/

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.navlinks', function() {
  $(this)
  .transition({perspective: '300px', rotateX: '360deg', rotateY: '360deg'})
  .transition({rotateX: 0, rotateY: 0, duration: 0});
});
```

Comment: they work just as they do on my page, i want them to hover again on the same element without having to reload the page. Need to  use mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Comment: When I run your fiddle it does exactly what the original poster says, works the first time only.